# Setup adwords cross-domain(subdomain) conversion tracking

Tags: google-ads

How can i setup cross domain conversion tracking with adwords?

My main site is "www.mainsite.com"

My conversion goal is visit "apply.mainsite.com" and login.

Comment: It sounds like you have a subdomain situation not a cross-domain.   For a subdomain you can have GA set the cookie at the domain level and tracking across both works seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Adwords does not support cross domain tracking however Google Analytics (AKA GA) does. Simply link your adwords account to your GA account. Below are quotes from Google's Answer pages, they are snippets and for full information you should visit each source.

***Link Adwords With Google Analytics***

> [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en)
>
> Link AdWords and Analytics
>
> The linking wizard makes it easy to link your AdWords account(s) to multiple views of your Analytics property. If you have multiple Analytics properties that want to link to your AdWords account(s), complete the linking process for each property.
>
> 1. [Sign in to Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/). *Note: You can also open Analytics from within your AdWords account. Click the **Tools** tab, select **Analytics**, and then follow the rest of these instructions.*
> 2. Click Admin and navigate to the property you want to link.
> 3. In the *PROPERTY* column, click **AdWords Linking**.
> 4. Click **+ NEW LINK GROUP**
> 5. Select the AdWords accounts you want to link, then click **Continue**.
> 6. Turn linking **ON** for each view in the property in which you want AdWords data.
> 7. Optionally, select **Enable Google Display Network Impression Reporting** to also include that data in each view.
> 8. If you've already enabled auto-tagging in your AdWords accounts, or if you want to let the linking process automatically enable auto-tagging in your AdWords accounts, skip to the next step (9). However, if you want to manually tag your AdWords links, click **Advanced settings > Leave my auto-tagging settings as they are**.
> 9. Click **Link accounts**.
>
> Congratulations! Your accounts are now linked. If you opted to
>   use auto-tagging (recommended), Analytics will start
>   automatically associating your AdWords data with customer clicks.

***Setup Cross Domain Tracking in GA***

> [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en)
>
> Set up cross-domain tracking (analytics.js)
>
> Cross-domain tracking makes it possible for Analytics to see sessions on two related sites (such as an ecommerce site and a separate shopping cart site) as a single session. This is sometimes called *site linking*.
>
> To set up cross-domain tracking, you'll need to be comfortable editing HTML and coding in JavaScript, or have help from an experienced web developer.
>
> Set up cross-domain tracking by modifying the tracking code
>
> To set up cross-domain tracking for multiple top-level domains, you need to modify the Analytics tracking code on each domain. You should have a basic knowledge of HTML and JavaScript or work with a developer to set up cross domain tracking. The examples in this article use the Universal Analytics tracking code snippet (analytics.js).
>
> ```
>   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
>   ga('require', 'linker');
>   ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-2.com']);
> ```

E.g use linker using `['shop.example.com', 'www.example.com']);`